# does closing a file opened with os.fdopen close the os-level fd?

Tags: python, file-io, operating-system

I'm making a temporary file with `tempfile.mkstemp()`. It returns an os-level fd along with the path to the file. I want to `os.fdopen()` the os-level file descriptor to write to it. If I then close the file that `os.fdopen()` returned, will the os-level file descriptor be closed, or do I have to `os.close()` it explicitly? The docs don't seem to say what happens explicitly.

Answer (score 10):

I'm pretty sure the fd will be closed. If you don't want that you can dup it first. Of course you can always test this easily enough.

Test is like this:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import os
import tempfile
import errno

fd, tmpname = tempfile.mkstemp()
fo = os.fdopen(fd, "w")
fo.write("something\n")
fo.close()
try:
    os.close(fd)
except OSError as oserr:
    if oserr.args[0] == errno.EBADF:
            print ("Closing file has closed file descriptor.")
    else:
        print ("Some other error:", oserr)
else:
    print ("File descriptor not closed.")
```

Which shows that the underlying file descriptor is closed when the file object is closed.